# Import existing users into new Windows7 install

Tags: windows, windows-7, user-management

I put in the effort to move my user's profiles onto a different drive.

I'd like to do an upgrade to Windows7, but I'm wondering how I can import the exiting users on the second drive into the new install.

I know that Windows Easy Transfer exists, but that requires copying the data to other media, is there any ability to add existing users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the User State Migration Tool: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560801(WS.10).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

[Registry Settings for Folder Redirection in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242557)
or
[How to Change a Personal User Folder Location in Vista](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/107990-personal-user-shell-folders-move-location.html)